# Why does the await call for my custom promise hang?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, mocha.js

I am trying to test a function in my Express/Node backend using Mocha. I have created a stub of the actual parameter which is modified by the function: it has a `send` method which is called in getValue (the function I want to test) and a `ready` parameter which I initialize to a new promise when the stub is created and resolve when `send` is called on the stub.

I'm trying to `await` this promise, but it's just hanging (and then Mocha times out the test). The setTimeout below prints `Promise { 'abc' }`, which I think means the promise has resolved as I expect it to, but the await never completes.

This is the relevant code in the test file:

```
function ResStubTemplate() {
        return {
                _json: undefined,
                _message: undefined,
                json: function(x) {
                        this._json = x;
                        return this;
                },
                send: function(message) {
                        this._message = message;
                        this.ready = Promise.resolve("abc");
                        return this;
                },
                ready: new Promise(_ => {})
        }
}

// This is the test
it("should get the value.", async function(done) {
        let req = { query: { groupId: 12345 } };
        res = ResStubTemplate();
        controller.getValue(req, res);
        setTimeout(() => console.log(res.ready), 1000); // prints Promise { 'abc' }
        let x = await res.ready; // hangs??
        console.log(x); // never prints
        done();
}
```

This is the relevant code in the tested file:

```
exports.getValue = function(req, res) {
        ValueModel.findOne({groupId: req.query.groupId})
           .then(value => res.json({value: value}).send();                                                                                                         
};
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded. 
For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise,
ensure it resolves. (/.../test/api/controller_test.js)
```

Comment: `new Promise(_ => {})` This will never resolve.

Answer (score 4):

When the expression:

> ```
> let x = await res.ready; // hangs??
> ```

… is evaluated, the value is the promise created by this code:

> ```
> ready: new Promise(_ => {})
> ```

That promise **never** resolves, so it keeps waiting for it.

Later you do this:

> ```
>  this.ready = Promise.resolve("abc");
> ```

… which replaces that promise with a new (resolved) promise, but the *new* promise isn't the value that you are awaiting.